# Jquery height function not correctly reporting height of content div

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dom, for-loop

I have a wordpress site width a sidebar where the client wants to repeat a set of ads over and over to fill the white space.

So I have the first set of ads hard-coded, then have a function that gets the height of the #content DIV and loops through an array of the ads and appends them to the sidebar as needed.

It works fine on most every page of the site, [such as here (link)](http://happeninginthehills.com/goings-on/).

But for some reason, the pages based on one template are not reporting the correct height (i put a trace statement to the page and it reported ~2500 instead of ~6000).  You can see that on [pages like this (link)](http://happeninginthehills.com/onourradar/recycled-reworked-and-reinvented/).

To make this harder to debug, intermittently it DOES work on those pages.  But usually a reload then it fails again.  The loop works, just not enough times since the height is incorrectly reported to the script.  I don't get it.

The script is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
    var adList = [
        '<a href="http://www.toveromarks.com"><img class="ad" src="http://happeninginthehills.com/wp-content/uploads/ads/ToveroHappeningHills.jpg" /></a>',
        '<img class="ad" src="http://happeninginthehills.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/vi-owens-ad.png" />', 
        '<a href="http://www.hadunne.com"><img class="ad" src="http://happeninginthehills.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/susie-ad1.png" /></a>', 
        '<a href="http://www.deborahchabrian.com"><img class="ad" src="http://happeninginthehills.com/wp-content/uploads/ads/chabrian-ad.jpg" /></a>',
        '<a href="http://www.tclaw.biz"><img class="ad" src="http://happeninginthehills.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/jeffs-ad.png" /></a>',
        '<a href="http://www.edmartinezart.com"><img class="ad" src="http://happeninginthehills.com/wp-content/uploads/ads/martinez-ad.jpg" /></a>',
        '<img class="ad" src="http://happeninginthehills.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/scott-phillips-ad.jpg" />'
        ];
    var adHeight = 285;
    var numRequiredAds = adList.length;
    var heightDiff = contentHeight - (numRequiredAds * adHeight);
    var numAds = Math.floor(heightDiff/adHeight);
    if (heightDiff > adHeight){
        for (var i = 0; i < numAds ; i++) {
            $('#primary').append(adList[i % adList.length]);
            //$('#primary').append('<p>ad num '+i+'</p>');
        };
            //$('#primary').append('<p>height is'+contentHeight+'</p>');
        }
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: confused on which element is not reporting the correct height?

Comment: Sorry, `$('#content').height();` is the one. The div id content is the main div whose height I am matching.

Comment: are you doing this in document.ready ? or window.onload.  It may not be getting height of images yet if they are not loaded

Comment: good point.  which should I be using?

Comment: for images use window.onload especially in chrome or safari document.ready should work with FF

Comment: i see it works fine in firefox but its not working on chrome i've run into this problem before

Comment: thanks so much.  i normally use document.ready.  i did not know this.

Comment: what browsers are you testing on?

Comment: i use chrome and the client uses safari.  i guess never tried FF.  i believe we tested IE9 on Win 7.

Comment: document.ready is quicker than window.onload because it doesn't wait for images to fully load so if your client is unhappy with load times if your using window.onload i usually just put an animated gif and remove it once all images have been loaded - glad to be of help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
   // your code
}
```